# Three.js birds demo not showing a css background image in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, three.js

My code shows a background image in both Safari and Firefox but not google Chrome. I am unsure why. I assume I'll need to do something to the following but I'm not sure what:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); 
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
```

Below is the CSS:

```
    body {
        background-image: url('beautiful.jpg');

        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Like I said it works perfectly in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome. Any idea's greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: Thanks but I have found the solution! Here is the js:     renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

Answer (score 0):

Transparent renderer backgrounds in three.js require the following two lines of code.

```
// tell three.js that the render background is transparent
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
// tell three.js to set the render background color to black with zero intensity (transparent)
renderer.setClearColor ( 0x000000, 0 );
```